# Validating Array to Array Exist in Lambda or Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, lambda

How to check whether `array2` is subset of `array1` or not? In other words I want to check whether all elements of `array2` are present in `array1` or not? I want solution in `Lambda` or `Linq`.

```
int[] array1 = {6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2};
int[] array2 = {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: thank you for the modification and correction for my boring sentence and grammatical mistakes :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question:

```
using System.Linq;

if (!array2.Except(array1).Any())
{
    ...validated!
}
```

Comment: hello @Alessandro from above array1 and array2 the result is "true"

when i tested the array with elements below..  the result is "false" any idea? thank you

int[] array1 = { 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2 };
int[] array2 = { 11, 12, 6, 4, 3};

if (!array2.Except(array1).Any())
{
  Console.WriteLine("true");
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("false");
}

Comment: It's correct because not all the elements of array2 exist inside array1.

Comment: mmhmm i already tested the code with another elements.. the result is false

Comment: yes.. from the first example of mine the result is true.. but i want to check the array2 if exist in array1 elements in any order of elements

Comment: array2 does not exist in array1 because items 11 and 12 are not available inside array1.

Comment: yes.. i got your point, but my point is to check the array if the element exist in another array in any order, even 1 element is exist the result will be true :)

Comment: So your question is incorrect, because it says: "I want to check whether ALL elements of array2 are present in array1 or not"

Comment: To check for one match try this: if (arrayElement2.Intersect(arrayElement1).Any())

Answer (score 1):

Another simple `LINQ`, you can use [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) to check whether all items of `array2` in `array1`:

```
if (array2.All(array1.Contains))
{
    // array2 is subset of array1
}
```

Comment: if you use your given function and the elements is like from my first example the result is true, but if you try to change the elements in any order the result is false. try this 

            `int[] array1 = { 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2 };
            int[] array2 = { 11, 1, 2, 3};

            var s = array2.All(array1.Contains);`

the correct answer is from @Alessandro  if `(array2.Intersect(array1 ).Any())`

Comment: @spajce: `int[] array1 = { 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2 }; int[] array2 = { 11, 1, 2, 3};` it is false of course because 11 does not belong to array1

Answer (score 1):

Try with,

```
 int[] array1 = { 6, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2 };
 int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3 };

 bool isSubset = array2.Count(o => array1.Contains(o)).Equals(array2.Count()) ? true : false;
```